# Cordova project giving 404 on php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cordova

Using my local to test my cordova project and in the console its telling me my test.php page is not found even though it is in the correct location. I know it is correct because my css and js do not give me an issue. Any idea this issue?
I tried GET as well & I also did not forget to install

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
```

Heres my directory :

- www/index.html
- www/php/test.php
- www/css/index.css
- www/js/jquery3.2.js

Index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery3.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() 
        {
               alert("alert 1");   //test alert 1         
               $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'php/test.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Simple Form test</h1>   
             <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
    <?php
       echo "alert 2";
    ?>
```

Comment: When i click on the 404 error in the console  http://localhost:8000/php/insert.php it downloads it fine

Comment: so i tested it with mamp and it works, could it be a server issue?